# Is Identity Column supported in Oracle NoSQL Database Cloud Service?

Tags: nosql, oracle-nosql

I ran the following DDL to create a new table using the service console. I created an identity column name appid. There was no error during the table creation.

```
CREATE Table demoTable(
    userid INTEGER,
    name STRING,
    appid INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (CACHE 1),
PRIMARY KEY(userid))
```

Everything looks fine, but when inserting a row, the service console still prompted me to enter the appid field.

I typed DEFAULT for appid, the error shows “Must be an integer”.

I tested the same insert in the on-prem product, it worked fine with the following command:

```
 insert into demoTable values (1,'myname',DEFAULT);
```

Is this a bug in the service console for inserting the identity column?

Answer (score 0):

identity columns are not supported in the console you need to create them directly from your app
from oracle docs :
Identity Columns: Identity columns are a special type of columns that get their values automatically assigned by Oracle NoSQL Database Cloud Service. These values are generated from a sequence generator. Identity columns are not supported from the NoSQL Database Cloud Service console.